Examine whether group members make the same choices
A MWE.
df <- tibble(ID = c(1:12),
             Group = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3)),
             Choice = c( rep(1.5, 3), round(rnorm(n=9,mean=10,sd=5), digits = 1) )
             )

What I want is to identify, in each group, whether the group members decisions are the same or not. The desired output should be something like:
df <- tibble(ID = c(1:12),
             Group = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3)),
             Choice = c( rep(1.5, 3), round(rnorm(n=9,mean=10,sd=5), digits = 1) )，
             Symmetric = c ( rep(1, 3), rep(0, 9) )
             )

Is there a fast and simple solution for this? Thanks a lot!

Couple of ideas -

You may count the unique values per group.

library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Symmetric = as.integer(n_distinct(Choice) == 1), .by = Group)

In base R :
transform(df, Symmetric = as.integer(ave(Choice, Group, FUN = \(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)))


since Choice is a numeric value we can also check it's standard deviation sd

df %>% mutate(Symmetric = as.integer(sd(Choice) == 0), .by = Group)

In base R :
transform(df, Symmetric = as.integer(ave(Choice, Group, FUN = sd) == 0))

All of which return :
#   ID Group Choice Symmetric
#1   1     1    1.5         1
#2   2     1    1.5         1
#3   3     1    1.5         1
#4   4     2    9.7         0
#5   5     2   -0.2         0
#6   6     2   12.9         0
#7   7     3   23.7         0
#8   8     3    2.3         0
#9   9     3   12.5         0
#10 10     4    7.5         0
#11 11     4    2.0         0
#12 12     4   14.0         0


The variance of the Choice values will be 0 iff they are the same and ! will transform that to TRUE and + will transform it to 1.
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Symmetric = +!var(Choice), .by = Group)

giving
# A tibble: 12 × 4
      ID Group Choice Symmetric
   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>     <int>
 1     1     1    1.5         1
 2     2     1    1.5         1
 3     3     1    1.5         1
 4     4     2   22.6         0
 5     5     2   12.7         0
 6     6     2   11.2         0
 7     7     3    4.8         0
 8     8     3   16.5         0
 9     9     3   14.1         0
10    10     4    9.7         0
11    11     4    6.1         0
12    12     4    6.3         0


Thanks for the explanation! That is very nice! why by argument has a . before it? What does it do? Thanks a lot!

Is adding .by = Group equilvalent to adding group_by(Group) %>% in front of mutate...?

Look at ?mutate or args(mutate) to see that it uses .by  with a dot.  It is mostly  equivalent to group_by although there are a few subtle difference explained here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_by.html

Thans a lot! Will check the link and learn about the differences between them~

> df %>% mutate(Symmetric = +(var(Choice) == 0), .by = Group)
# A tibble: 12 × 4
      ID Group Choice Symmetric
   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>     <int>
 1     1     1    1.5         1
 2     2     1    1.5         1
 3     3     1    1.5         1
 4     4     2   16.6         0
 5     5     2    6.4         0
 6     6     2    7.5         0
 7     7     3   13.7         0
 8     8     3   16           0
 9     9     3    8.2         0
10    10     4    2           0
11    11     4    9.2         0
12    12     4   15.1         0

